# Intersection Area in C

Tags: c, arrays

Assume that I have 5 rectangle, and each rectangle has 4 parameters,
these are x,y,width,height. x and y -> start coordination, w and h ->edges. How we calculate intersection area ?

```
 int rectangle[5][4];

    int calculate_intersection(){
    ....
    return total;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `struct` with expressive field names instead of an array of four values to represent a rectangle?

Comment: I don't know struct, I am new student, We did not do this lesson

Comment: This is more of a math problem, not a programming one.

Comment: @SefaTaşcan Read stackoverflow rules, assignments are not made here, help with programming problems.

Comment: It is not assignment, It is my own work.

Comment: google, google, google. Is this a question about `struct` or about geometry?

Comment: Get a pen and some paper and think about how to do it for 2 rectangles. Then "fold" that operation over your rectangles, read: apply it to two rectangles, then one rectangle and the result etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to iteratively make new rectangles, each being the intersection of the previous. Let's say you have four rectangles, call them `Ri` where `i` is `1, 2, 3,` or `4`. Let's call the intersection rectangle `I4`, for the intersection of the 4 rectangles.

First we will want to intersect `R1` and `R2`. Save the resulting `width`, `height`, `x`, and `y` into `I4`.

Next we will want to intersect `R3` and `I4`. Save the resulting `width`, `height`, `x`, and `y` into `I4`.

Then we will want to intersect `R4` and `I4`. Save the resulting `width`, `height`, `x`, and `y` into `I4`.

At this point `I4` is the result of intersecting all 4 rectangles, `R1, R2, R3,` and `R4`. I'm sure you will now know how to calculate the area given these values.

***: : Hints and pseudo code for finding intersection : :***

Given the rectangles may be in any orientation and position relative to one another, we'll need to do a little work in figuring out where points lie in respect to each other. Typically, we'll use the `MAX` and `MIN` function, or you can use these one-liners:

```
int max = (a>b) ? a : b;
int min = (a<b) ? a : b;
```

`max` here will hold the value of either `a` or `b`, whichever is greater, and 'min' will hold the lesser. Now with this we can solve for our points.

To find `I4` `x`-value, we'll need to take the max's of the `Ri` and `Rj` rectangles in the x-direction:  `I4x = max{Ri_x, Rj_x}`

To find `I4` `y`-value, we'll need to take the max's of the `Ri` and `Rj` rectangles in the y-direction:  `I4y = max{Ri_y, Rj_y}`

To find `I4` `width`-value, we'll need to take the min's of the `Ri` and `Rj` rectangles *total* width, *BUT* we will need to subtract away the final shifted `x` location:  `I4w = min{Ri_x + Ri_w, Rj_x + Rj_w} - I4_x`

To find `I4` `height`-value, similarily we'll need to take the min's of the `Ri` and `Rj` rectangles *total* height and subtract away the final shifted `y` location:  `I4w = min{Ri_y + Ri_h, Rj_y + Rj_h} - I4_y`

Comment: how do to intersect ? It is main problem

Comment: @SefaTaşcan: drawn an ASCII diagram of two rectangles that intersect; work out the description of the intersection in terms of the x, y, width, height values of the two rectangles.  That's how you do it.  If you've not yet learned structures, then have another go at this exercise when you have learned them (next week, or the week after?).  You might find that 'bottom left, top right' corners are easier to manipulate than width and height, though the two forms are interchangeable.  This assumes that the rectangles are aligned with the axes; if they're at arbitrary angles, you need more info.

Comment: @SefaTaşcan, Hints/pseudo help?